# How to open a URL from MS Access with parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access, url

I have a basic MS Access application that has a button on a form that should open a webpage with the ID of the Access record as the parameter, but everything I have tried results either in an error by Access or only the base URL opening in the web page.

I have tried adding VBA to the button's click event as so:

```
Application.FollowHyperlink _ 
"http://example.com/index.php?r=controller/action&id=" & Me.ID
```

but all I get is the base URL opening on the web browser (ie http://example.com).  If I remove the '?' and the '&' from the full URL the button will open the browser with the full URL minus the '?' and the '&', which of course errors the page.

I have tried setting a hyperlink control's property as:

```
="http://example.com/index.php?r=controller/action&id=" & Me.ID
```

but it does the same thing as noted above.

I have tried creating a Macro with the same results.  I have tried using the Hyperlink Builder and using `[formName]![id]` as the parameter but same thing happens or Access errors.

I have read this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822080.aspx and tried adding the part in the URl after 'index.php/ to the ExtraInfo place in the code, but same thing.

Help! It can't be that hard to simply have Access open a URL with a parameter on the end of the URL.

Comment: Can't you simply create a string like this: `str_url = "http://example.com/index.php?r=controller/action&id=" & Me.ID` and then open it from Application.FollowHyperlink? It should probably work.

Comment: It absolutely SHOULD be that simple, but this is Microsoft we're talking about and no that doesn't work.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Application.FollowHyperlink` is fickle.

Use either `ShellExecute`:
[Open an html page in default browser with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166265/open-an-html-page-in-default-browser-with-vba)

or

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open "http://example.com/index.php?r=controller/action&id=" & Me.ID
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18922262/3820271

---

If the URL is in a string variable, you may need to cast it to Variant, because that's what Shell.Application.Open expects:

```
strUrl = "http://example.com/index.php?r=controller/action&id=" & Me.ID
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open CVar(strUrl)
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56173911/3820271, thanks Toby and Anthony for pointing this out!

Comment: That works!!!  Thank you so much!  I simply added your code line above to the click event for the button and it opens just fine.  Gotta love Microsoft simplicity <--sarcasm.  Thanks again!  I tried to upvote your answer but I don't have the rep to do it.  I'm sorry.  But that is absolutely the right answer.

Comment: If you are having issues with this not working try combining it with @TobyOvod-Evertt suggestion as well.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you are having issues with `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open` not working with a variable, it might be a casting issue - try tossing a `CVar()` around the parameter.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56173911/8512931 for more details.

Comment: I started to write off the accepted answer as not working until I tried this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This VBA opens Edge with the desired URL.  See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/880683/how-to-open-the-edge-browser-using-vba-macro).

```
Private Sub lst_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Dim varURL As Variant
    varURL = CVar(lst.Column(1, 0))
    If Len(varURL & "") > 0 Then
        CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "microsoft-edge:" & varURL & """" ' open [expects a variant][2];
 End If
    GoTo CleanUp
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume CleanUp
    Resume 'debugging only
CleanUp:
End Sub
```