# VBA Application.FollowHyperlink how to send http headers to web server such as User-Agent

Tags: vba, ms-access, hyperlink

I always use `Application.FollowHyperlink` on VBA to launch the default web browser such as Microsoft Edge under Windows 10. I shall avoid Shell.Application or dll ShellExecute().

But now some usually accessed web site has added User-Agent control. If it's not set, the web server refuses my request with a

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

response.

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.followhyperlink),

```vb
Application.FollowHyperlink Address, SubAddress, NewWindow, AddHistory, ExtraInfo, Method, _
  HeaderInfo
```

But I cannot send HeaderInfo, as I tried this:

```vb
Application.FollowHyperlink "https://www.example.com", "", false, false, "", 0, _
  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"
```

without any success.

VBA error messageBox popups

[image]

In English: Running error '8': cannot download requested data (Cannot Download the information you requested).

---

To prove the header problem,
`curl` also failed without User-Agent header (error HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden):

```
curl -I https://www.example.com
```

[image]

But it worked under Powershell console like this:

```
curl -I -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36" https://www.example.com
```

[image]

What's the good syntax for HeaderInfo on VBA to send http User-Agent header to web server, any idea ?

Comment: Did you try adding as part of querystring? Also, could you make it looks like hyperlinks but actually have event code/controls tied to following method, which may be more reliable according to the authors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462176/how-to-open-a-url-from-ms-access-with-parameters  Failing that, depending on requirements, use xhr? Don't know how user is interacting with the link.

Comment: Thank you @QHarr for your attention. Tried Application.FollowHyperlink "https://www.example.com?User-Agent=Chrome", "", false, false, "", 0,  "" without access, but curl -I -H "User-Agent: Chrome" OK.