# Is there any method equivalent for "FollowHyperlink" in Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there any method in Outlook VBA equivalent to Excel's `FollowHyperlink`?

I made an Excel VBA macro that posts the text in the clipboard to a specific site using `FollowHyperlink` method.

I want to do the same thing with Outlook VBA but I couldn't find the method.

Any method that does the same thing as simply as `FollowHyperlink` is quite fine.

Here is the Excel VBA version of a function that post the content of the clipboard to Google translation. I want to make an Outlook version of this one.

```
Public Sub GoogleTranslate_2EN()
    Dim clipBoard As New DataObject
    With clipBoard
    On Error Resume Next
        .GetFromClipboard
        Dim targetText As String
        targetText = .GetText
    On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://translate.google.co.jp/?hl=en&tab=wT#auto/en/" & targetText

    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=URL, newWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your current code we maybe able to modify it to  outlook vba

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open an html page in default browser with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3166265/11683)

Comment: I tried using shell as the code in the article "Open an html page in default browser with VBA?". Using shell doesn't do HTML encoding which FollowHyperlink does.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use Word.Application object and use "FollowHyperlink" from a Word object. It worked!

Now I can Google translate emails in Germany to English as soon as I receive them. :-)

```
Public Sub ClipboardGoogleTranslate_2EN()

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    wdApp.Run "ClipboardGoogleTranslate_2EN"

    wdApp.Quit

    Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```