# ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink doesn't seem to open a Google Form (MS Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, google-forms

In my VBA Code I am using this command to open my google form in front of the user -

```
Dim URL As String
URL = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/my-form/viewform?usp=sf_link"
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink URL
```

But when this code is executed, it opens this specific page -  https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6283888 for some strange reason... Why is this happening? I've tried using full google form link, google form short link & even a bit.ly based link - but all lead the same to that support page...

What should I do if I want to open my form in front of my user through VBA? Kindly guide... Thanks! :)

Comment: I guess _FollowHyperlink_ opens directly Internet Explorer and not an modern browser. Maybe you can use e.g. [ShellExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3166322/17172829) instead.

Comment: `FollowHyperlink` should open URL in the **default browser**. I think it is/was enough to change the default browser application to be Chrome...