# Excel Macro opening Website not working on different computers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that allows me to open a website using Chrome.

I've found an easy code online which works fine for what I need, but I need it to work on different computer also, which it doesn't.

```vb
Sub Test()
    navigate = "website"
    Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url " & navigate)
End Sub
```

The problem that I saw while trying to fix it was that the path to chrome.exe is different on each computer.

How can I fix it so that the macro finds the app itself without having to hardcode the path?

Comment: Does it have to be chrome? if the default browser is ok, then check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166265/open-an-html-page-in-default-browser-with-vba

Comment: No i doesnt have to be, i looked at the related post you linked and it fixed my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about open the url with default browser

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub OpenURL()
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    Shell "cmd /c start " & url, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it on my computer and it "worked" as it opened the website, but it crashes my Excel window and when I open it back, it doesnt work anymore. Havent even tried on another computer.

Comment: I have tested it on Win 11 + Office 365 w/o any issures.